# Two buttons with same id and same behavior in android

Tags: android, android-button

I want to navigate two buttons to the same class. In one XML, I have two buttons, both should work the same way. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can't use same id in the same XML. and what did you mean by same behavior?

Comment: Add same listener to both buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Define two button with different id and point to same function in `onClick` event

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="executeSameBehavior"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="executeSameBehavior"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2" />
```

And then implement your logic here:

```
public void executeSameBehavior(View view) {
    // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign one clickListener interface to both `setOnClickListener`s

```
Button a = findViewById(R.id.a);
Button b = findViewById(R.id.b);

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Something for both
    }
};

a.setOnClickListener(listener);
b.setOnClickListener(listener);
```